# Does Coderwall support emoticons?

Tags: emoji, coderwall

Does Coderwall support emoticons or emoji of any kind - or is the site too serious-minded for that?

I was trying to put a smiley face in one of my posts. I am not very emoji-intelligent, but it didn't format fancy.

Any way to get this to work?